# Empty list when tail of singly linked list is null

Tags: linked-list

It seems that people always say that if the head of a singly linked list is null, then the list is empty, but would checking the tail work as well? Supposing I know for sure that a list has a tail for sure, can I check if the tail is null to determine if it's empty?

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest implementation of singly linked list you keep the reference to a "node" struct, which contains both the value and the reference to the tail.

If the list is empty, this reference is null. You don't have neither a value, nor a tail.

If the list contains at least one element, then the reference points to the head.

Answer (score 0):

For a singly linked list, I assume that you are keeping pointers or references to the 'head' node and the 'tail' node. If this is the case, the answer depends on how you handle setting these references.

> Case 1 - The 'tail' is not set until there are at least two nodes.
>
> > 0 Nodes in list: The 'head' and 'tail' are both null.
> >
> > 1 Node in list: The 'head' is set, but the 'tail' is null.
> >
> > 2+ Nodes in list: The 'head' and 'tail' are both set, to different nodes.
>
> Case 2 - The 'tail' is always set if the head is set.
>
> > 0 Nodes in list: The 'head' and 'tail' are both null.
> >
> > 1 Node in list: The 'head' and 'tail' are both set, to the same node.
> >
> > 2+ Nodes in list: The 'head' and 'tail' are both set, to different nodes.

Case 1 makes sense if you have data where you want a single node to mean something special, like a dead end or outlier. Here you're choice to check the list for the tail's existence to determine an empty list would fail.

Case 2 is simpler to code and requires fewer decisions. The head is always the first node, and the tail is always the last node, even if they are the same node. Here your choice to check for the tail's existence makes perfect sense.

If you want to check the tail, just make sure you check the specification of your library or build your own list to the spec of case 2.